# how to auto-delete the queue if using spring + stomp + full broker with rabbitmq

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, stomp

in spring doc,  For example, RabbitMQ creates auto-delete queues when destinations like /exchange/amq.direct/position-updates are used

I tried a few times, but I cannot make it work to auto-delete the queue. pls help give more details, such as
1. how to set the url for subscribe on client side?
2. any setting need to be done in rabbitmq in advanced?
3. how to set the url in controller?

Comment: Temporary queues might be what you are looking for, they are explained on the https://rabbitmq.com/stomp.html page. `Each /temp-queue/ corresponds to a distinct anonymous, exclusive, auto delete queue.`

Comment: @mjn, actually we need user destination to respond message to particular user, not broadcasting, so anonymous is not applicable to my case

Comment: I developed a STOMP client for RabbitMQ and other brokers, and with temp queues, the client who created the temp queue use the `reply-to` header to pass the temp queue name to other applications which in turn can use the temp queue name to send messages to that client. I have no idea what `anonymous` means, as a temp queue has a name.

Answer (score 1):

If you use topic exchange and forward the message to broker with a routing key, it automatically creates auto delete queues. You dont need to have any special configuration.